# Buscar elemento en un array y devolver a sus vecinos inmediatos

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, condiciones, objeto

La funcion recibe un objeto `menu` que contiene las comidas del día, "comida" es un array de ingredientes.

Si `ingrediente` está en el array de ingredientes de la comida, devolver un array con el `ingrediente` y los elementos a la izquerda y derecha en un índice de diferencia.

Ejemplo:

```javascript
let menuDelDia = {
  raviolesConSalsa: ["Harina", "Sal", "Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
  bagnaCauda: ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"]
};

ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Peceto"); // Devuelve => ["Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"];
```

En caso de no encontrarse el ingrediente en la comida, devolver "El menú está perfecto".

**NOTA:** No utilizar el método `.includes()`.

Este fue mi intento, sin embargo se que esta mal:

```javascript
function ingredienteEnMalEstado(menu, comida, ingrediente) {
  var nuevoArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < menu[comida].length; i++) {
    if (menu[comida[i]] === ingrediente) {
      nuevoArray.push(menu[comida[i] - 1]);
      nuevoArray.push(menu[comida[i]]);
      nuevoArray.push(menu[comida[i] + 1]);
    }
    else if ((menu[comida[i]] !== ingrediente)) {
      return "El menú está perfecto";
    }
  }

  return nuevoArray;
};
```

Comment: Hola @maria bienvenida a SOEs, tengo un par de preguntas y observaciones acerca de tu problema. En el ejemplo haces referencia a una función llamada `ingredienteEnMalEstado()` pero luego en tu código hay otra función llamada `MalEstado()`, ¿son dos funciones diferentes?. Podrías explicar con un poco más de detalle el funcionamiento de la función, es decir, ¿qué pasó con los elementos `['Harina', 'Sal', 'Huevos']` al colocar los parámetros mostrados? ¿cuál es el criterio para descartarlos de los ingredientes? Por último te invito a realizar el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: hola,son la misma funcion, me confundi pero ya lo edite. solo debe ser mostrado el ingrediente que se ingresa y los que estan a su derecha e izquierda osea con un indice de diferencia

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo, y ¿qué pasa si la comida no se encuentra en el menú?

Comment: tengo la duda de ¿para que retornas nuevoArray?, si lo que deseas es saber si esta buen seria mejor retornar un boleano

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no funciona porque dentro del ciclo `for`, en el bloque `else if` tienes un `return` que terminará la ejecución de la función a la primera oportunidad que el ingrediente que recorres sea diferente al ingrediente que buscas, es decir, si buscas un ingrediente `b` y tu primer elemento es `a`, esto provocará que el código entre en ese bloque y se ejecute el `return` lo que finalizará la ejecución, aún cuando haya más elementos por visitar.

Lo que puedes hacer para facilitar un poco el proceso es verificar que la `comida` exista en el `menu`. Si no existe aquí puedes decir que el menú está perfecto (o tratarlo con un error por ejemplo). Luego si la `comida` existe entonces puedes iterar sobre los ingredientes pertenecientes a esta comida y en caso de encontrar el `ingrediente` simplemente validas en dónde te encuentras; si te encuentras en el inicio, no hay elemento a la izquierda; si te encuentras al final, no hay elemento a la derecha, si estás en cualquier otra posición, hay elemento a la izquierda y a la derecha.

Al final validas que `nuevoArray` contenga ingredientes, si está vacío "El menú está perfecto.". Si contiene elementos, esos serán los ingredientes en mal estado (¿o no?).

```js
let menuDelDia = {
  raviolesConSalsa: ["Harina", "Sal", "Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
  bagnaCauda: ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"]
};

function ingredienteEnMalEstado(menu, comida, ingrediente) {
  let nuevoArray = [];

  const ingredientes = menu[comida]; // Si la comida no existe, será undefined. Caso contrario, contendrá los ingredientes

  if (ingredientes && ingredientes.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ingredientes.length; i++) {
      if (ingredientes[i] === ingrediente) {
        if (i === 0) {
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i + 1]);
        } else if (i === ingredientes.length - 1) {
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i - 1]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i]);
        } else {
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i - 1]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i + 1]);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return nuevoArray.length ? nuevoArray : 'El menú está perfecto';
};

console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Harina")); // Sin elemento a la izquierda
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Peceto")); // Elemento a la izquierda y derecha
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Ricota")); // Sin elemento a la derecha
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "pizza", "Ricota"));            // Comida no existe en el menú
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "bagnaCauda", "Ricota"));       // Ingrediente no existe en los ingredientes
```

Answer (score 0):

**Otra solución:**

Podrías bucar el índice del ingrediente entre los ingredientes de la comida especificada `menuDelDia[comida]` con la función `findIndex()`.

- Si no encuentra el ingrediente (`findIndex` retorna -1) la función devuelve "El menú está perfecto!".
- Si encuentra el ingrediente hay que diferenciar dos casos. Si es el primer elemento del arreglo de ingredientes (entonces va a retornar solo 2 ingredientes (porque no hay un ingrediente anterior)), caso contrario retorna 3 ingredientes.

```js
function ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, comida, ingrediente) {
  var cantIngredientes = 3;
  let ingedientes = menuDelDia[comida];
    
  pos = ingedientes.findIndex((element) => element == ingrediente);
  
  if(pos == -1) {
    return "El menú está perfecto!";
  }
  
  pos > 0 ? pos -= 1 : cantIngredientes = 2;
   
  return ingedientes.slice(pos, pos + cantIngredientes);
}


let menuDelDia = {
  raviolesConSalsa: ["Harina", "Sal", "Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
  bagnaCauda: ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"]
};

let res = ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Peceto"); // Devuelve => ["Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let menuDelDia = {
  raviolesConSalsa: ["Harina", "Sal", "Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
  bagnaCauda: ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"]
};

function ingredienteEnMalEstado(menu, comida, ingrediente) {
  let nuevoArray = [];

  const ingredientes = menu[comida]; // Si la comida no existe, será undefined. Caso contrario, contendrá los ingredientes

  if (ingredientes && ingredientes.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ingredientes.length; i++) {
      if (ingredientes[i] === ingrediente) {
        if (i === 0) {
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i + 1]);
        } else if (i === ingredientes.length - 1) {
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i - 1]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i]);
        } else {
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i - 1]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i]);
          nuevoArray.push(ingredientes[i + 1]);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return nuevoArray.length ? nuevoArray : 'El menú está perfecto';
};

console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Harina")); // Sin elemento a la izquierda
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Peceto")); // Elemento a la izquierda y derecha
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Ricota")); // Sin elemento a la derecha
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "pizza", "Ricota"));            // Comida no existe en el menú
console.log(ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "bagnaCauda", "Ricota"));       // Ingrediente no existe en los ingredientes
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: buenos dias. esta muy buena su respuesta. Gracias. Me gustaria saber que pasa si yo le añado al menuDelDia, otra comida como por ejemplo; tallarines: ["Harina, "Pollo", "Aceite", "Huevos", "Tomate", "Ceboya"]. ¿ sirve ese mismo recorrido?, ¿O hay que añadir otro bucle?. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: ¿Estás autorrespondiéndote en un comentario de una respuesta que no está clara?

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/332498)